# Decode json like string in php

Tags: php, json

I have a string that is stored in a MySQL database (joomla) and starts with the below. Does anyone know what type of string this is and how I can decode it to an array in PHP? It looks similar to JSON but I am unsure.

```
a:4:{s:7:"Enabled";s:3:"yes";s:9:"StoreData";a:3:{i:1;a:9:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:7:"Enabled";s:3:"yes";s:4:"Name";a:1:{i:1;s:13:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its serialized string you have to unserialize it, manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

```
$your_string = unserialize($encoded_string)
```

where `$encoded_string` is the string from your db